# Inheritance Issue: facebookCategory doesn't have an 'isa', a 'sub' or an 'id'

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

Grakn is awesome, but it also seems very unstable.
The exactly same initial import queries -run in another keyspace- (meaning both were empty before) are only working in one keyframe, the other throws this stupid error:

`Error status: 400, error info: facebookCategory doesn't have an 'isa', a 'sub' or an 'id'`

In my scheme facebookCategory is defined like this `facebookCategory sub category`. Category is defined as `category is-abstract sub entity`.

So - what's wrong with Grakn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue we are working on right now:

when you start migrating data on a keyspace and for some reason your schema or data are wrong/missing, the keyspace sometimes gets corrupted. So when you will try to reload data - even if now everything is correct - you will get that error, again because the keyspace is corrupted.

We are working on this issue internally to solve it as soon as possible.

The error you get is trying to tell you that there is a corrupted schema, we will try to improve it and make it more explicit so that you don't think it's stupid.

We know Grakn is still far from perfect but we can assure you we are just trying to fix as many bugs as possible.

Please try to migrate everything in a clean keyspace, you can find also more issues discussed in our [github repo](https://github.com/graknlabs/grakn/issues) and our [support forum](https://discuss.grakn.ai/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and status report! And hey please don't get me wrong, I didn't meant you guys, but just my instance of Grakn :)

Comment: Ok right, updated the answer so that I also refer to Grakn and not to us, thank you!